# nginx extensionless php url without if statement

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I use this config:

```
root /www/mysite/static
location / {
    try_files $uri @php;
}
location @php {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/mysite/controller$fastcgi_script_name.php;
}
```

This will first check if /www/mysite/static has the file. If it can't find the file, then it will run fastcgi on "file.php".

Now if I go to www.mysite.com/asdf, it will try to run fastcgi with /www/mysite/controller/asdf.php, which doesn't exist.

I read that If statement is evil, so what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

```
location /info {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/www/info.php;
}
```

Actually makes sense now as I've bothered to read the documentation...